# Validate login page in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, testng-dataprovider

Hi I need to automate my login page and validate all error messages.
ie. With valid login and invalid password.
without entering the email and password.
here i need to validate the error messages displayed on the browser for all my login credentials.
Please tell me how to do this in page object model + data provider.

Answer (score 0):

You should create data provider sets for scenarios that you want to cover.
They should contain email, password and errorMessage fields if those are the only things that you wish to use.
Test will use these fields as parameters and errorMessage should be compared (assert) with control that holds error message.
What you need to do is to model your login page in page object model design pattern.
You can find more info about page object model [here](https://webkul.com/blog/page-object-model-pom-selenium/).
You can find more info about testng data provider with examples [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-parameters-data-provider/).
All this is said considering that you can find your way in Java, Selenium and TestNG.